# IE7 floating block inside absolutely positioned element with auto size

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

This [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/zhG9x/2/) looks identical in Opera, Chrome, Firefox & IE > 7. In IE7, the blue block is stuck to right side. Any idea how to fix layout in IE7 without specifying popup width?

HTML:

```
<div id="popup">
    <div class="content">content content content</div>
    <div class="buttons-container">
        <div class="buton"></div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
#popup {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    top: 10px;
    background: green;
}

.buttons-container {
    line-height: 32px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 12px;
}

.buton {
    display: block;
    min-width: 60px;
    height: 24px;
    background: blue;
}​
```

Comment: It's stuck to the right side in chrome also...

Comment: @A.M.K I have chrome 22 and it's ok there